# Изменить стиль css стороннего виджета iframe который загружает img с заданными параметрами

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

На сайте есть рекламный баннер, который загружает изображения через js с прописанными css, хотелось бы добавить max-width для оптимизации на мобильных версиях, как можно это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует именно манипуляции с динамическим img, до которого через css добраться не получается :(

Comment: Создайте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (пример нужен в виде текста, а не картинки), так шансы того что на ваш вопрос ответят, возрастут.

Comment: В чужой iframe добраться нельзя никак (если владелец iframe этого не предусмотрел)

Comment: Можете попробовать [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217833/13349770) и [это](https://only-to-top.ru/blog/coding/2019-10-03-css-to-iframe.html)